# Debug application which is run using pm2

Tags: pm2

Application is run by

```
pm2 start app.js
```

or

```
pm2 start config.json
```

I want to debug my application locally using node_inspector. I added `debug` argument

```
pm2 start --node-args="--debug=7000" app.js
```

It works fine but if I provide `config.json` instead of script `app.js` I don't know how to pass arguments about debug. Next piece of config doesn't work

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "myName",
      "script": "app.js",
      "args": "['--debug=7000']"
      ............
      }
    ]
}
```

So How to debug application which is run by pm2 and using config?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You're almost there, use `node_args` instead of `args`:

- `args` are your script arguments
- `node_args` are arguments that are passed to node executable

  ```
  {
    "name": "myName",
    "script": "app.js",
    "node_args": ["--debug=7000"]
  }
  ```

[PM2 json schema](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/blob/master/lib/API/schema.json).

If someone still has problems with the debug setting after this, in some case you have to disable the cluster mode for the debug setting to be effective.

Also note that you don't need the brackets in the node_args value if you pass all the args as a single string.

Comment: I am new to node and pm2, so what will happen if we add this argument? Will it add debug logs in pm2.log?

Comment: Nope `--debug` in `node_args` corresponds to the internal [node debugging port](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html).

Comment: If someone still has problems with the debug setting after this, in my case I had to disable the cluster mode for the debug setting to be effective. Also note that you don't need the brackets in the node_args value if you pass all the args as a single string.

Comment: @Herick Thank you so much. Yes indeed I had to switch exec_mode to "fork", otherwise it was using it's own ports. Update: now nodejs uses inspect cmd option. So command up there should be "--inspect=9090" etc.

Comment: Cluster comment made my day!

Comment: This works for PM2 v2.x but does not work with PM2 v3.
See https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/3227.

Comment: instead of debug i tried with inspect it worked for me like this   "node_args": ["--inspect"] and opened chrome chrome://inspect/#devices there you will find target you can click on the inspect link, :) One doubt whether it has hot reloading(fast refresh) like in create react app or every time i need to add debugger and restart the server

Comment: For me removing this: "exec_mode" : "cluster_mode" and using --inspect instead of --debug worked. Thanks.

Comment: Note that specifying `inspector-port` in `cluster` mode is not working: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/5301#issuecomment-1133784160

Comment: Application started at debug mode at
`ws://127.0.0.1:9230/beb99cb4-e9f6-4a7e-941f-d70b6391301f`
But how can I get hit it from postman ?

Answer (score 9):

[pm2 version 3.2.2]

The following would work if you want to attach Vscode with PM2.

In the ecosystem file which is ecosystem.config.js, add the following line under apps.

`node_args : ["--inspect"]`

Adding this would automatically set two node arguments while invoking the scripts. They are `--inspect`,`--inspect-port=9232`.

They can be seen with `console.log(process.process.execArgv)`

Also, if the number of instances are > 1, then the above argument would keep incrementing this port number for each other node instance under this pm2.

eg., for the second node instance pm2 would pass `--inspect`,`--inspect-port=9233`.

In case you explicitly set the inspect-port to a value I see the following as args
`--inspect`,`--inspect-port=9200`,`--inspect-port=9230`

And it doesn't seem to use the port you wanted. But I think given the nature of pm2, may be its better to not use a specific port.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

Another way to do it would be

```
env: {
    NODE_OPTIONS: '--inspect'
}
```

in your ecosystem.config.js file.

Comment: Strangely, this is the only solution, that works for me on a Debian server. The `node_args` is just ignore, while reported correctly as arguments passed to Node.

Comment: My pm2 application is running at debug port, but how should I access it. The debug logs shown as `ws://127.0.0.1:9230/beb99cb4-e9f6-4a7e-941f-d70b6391301f`

Comment: If you're using a yml file, just ignore the bracers