# Error: Cannot connect to runtime; make sure that runtime is in 'legacy' debug mode

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, pm2

I see the above when trying to debug Node.js script with Visual Studio Code.

My `launch.json` looks like

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Process",
            "protocol": "legacy",
            "processId": "${command:PickProcess}"
        }
    ]
}
```

No matter I put the line `"protocol": "legacy",` or not I get exactly the same error as above.
My environment
System: OSX
Node: v8.6.0
VSC: 1.17.2
Also, I run the node script with PM2.

Any suggestion would be hugely appreciated

Comment: Can  you try starting the process with --debug or --debug-brk  switch ?

Comment: @Akhil I've tried `>pm2 reload ecosystem.config.js --debug` which returned `error: unknown option `--debug'`

Comment: Not familiar with PM2 but with nodemon something like this works for me - "start": "nodemon --debug=5001 app.js", you can try using nodemon for the dev environment and see if it works for you

Comment: Also, take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29900253/debug-application-which-is-run-using-pm2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Node v8.6 does not support "legacy" protocol. You should use the "inspector" protocol.

Comment: How do I switch to the inspector protocol?

Comment: @kos just change the `protocol` in `launch.json` file.  `"protocol": "legacy",` => `"protocol": "inspector",`

Answer (score 1):

I ran above the same issue using the "legacy" protocol while running the Hello  World Extension. After searching a bit, I stumbled on [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/26411), and change my launch.json file to the following as suggested by @weinand:

```
{
        "name": "Launch Extension",
        "type": "extensionHost", 
        "request": "launch",
        "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
        "args": [ "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceRoot}" ],
        "outFiles": [ "${workspaceRoot}/out/src/**/*.js" ]
}
```

- using node 8.9.1
- used the latest version of the yeoman generator for the code.